# Is there any API to read SOLR config parameters?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I want to read one the parameters (maxBooleanClauses) specified in the solrconfig.xml at the client side. I tried to check if there is any API to do that, but didn't find any. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is not currently a way to get individual settings for the options in the solrconfig.xml file like there is for the schema (via [Schema REST API](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaRESTAPI)). You can configure Solr to make the entire solrconfig.xml file "gettable" via [The Admin/GUI Section](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#The_Admin.2FGUI_Section) settings. This would allow you to retrieve the file and parse it to determine the value of the `maxBooleanClauses` setting.